# Trading View for React Native

Tags: react-native, charts, tradingview-api

I am looking to implement Trading View charts in react-native but I cant seem to find anything but react documentation. Is there a react-native library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link:
https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/tree/master/react-native

A complete integration example for react-native can be found here.

Comment: having issue with android for above